# Extracting text from PDF scientific papers

Tags: python, pdf, spacy

I would like to extract text from a scientific document in PDF format.
I first used PyPDF2 but random spaces appear in the middle of several words.
I am currently using PyMUPDF

```py
import fitz
import re

def extract_pdf_text(pdf_file_path):
    doc = fitz.open(pdf_file_path)
    text = ""
    for page in doc:
        text += page.get_text("text")#.replace("\n", " ")
    return text

pdf_path = "/home/xxx/Papers/xxxxx.pdf"
text = extract_pdf_text(pdf_path)
text = re.sub(r"�", " ", text)
url_pattern = re.compile(r'http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+')
text = re.sub(url_pattern, 'replaced_link.', text)
text = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", text)
```

removing �, replacing url by fix word and remove extra space

The goal is to separate the text into sentences (I use Spacy).
But it failed in some places because the extracted text sticks with a space two distinct parts of the pdf (e.g. title and author).
I would like to paste them with a "\n" instead.

[image]

If I extract and dispatch in sentences I get

["See discussions, stats, and author profiles for this publication at: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313756771 HDSKG:", "Harvesting Domain Speciﬁc Knowledge Graph from Content of Webpages Conference Paper · February 2017"]

Instead of

["See discussions, stats, and author profiles for this publication at: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/313756771", "HDSKG:Harvesting Domain Speciﬁc Knowledge Graph from Content of Webpages", "Conference Paper · February 2017"]

Comment: It seems like your text is physically stored in a sequence different from natural reading sequence. This is a common problem. As a first measure, you could extract via `get_text(sort=True)`. If this doesn't help, your can extract by single words `get_text("words", sort=True)` and then glue together the words to complete sequences.
 Looking at your example however, I have no idea what may have caused this effect. So maybe we should use "Discussions" on the package's homepage to exchange more detals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jorj McKie, `get_text(sort=True)` worked a bit, mb for `text = re.sub(r"\s+", " ", text)` that was removing the "\n".